# Adapting pixels of the image depending files and rows

Tags: java, image, jlabel, pixel, imageicon

I have this function where I receive `String[][]`, `f` (rows), and `c` (columns). I've got to adapt my labels occupying all of my frame `(1270,750)`.

For example, if I receive:

- `f=3` and `c=3`, the images will have: `(423.333,250.)` pixels
- `f=10` and `c=10`, the images will have `(127,75)` pixels.

I've proved with all the functions which are in the example, but it doesn't work. Any idea how to do it?

```
public void inicialitzamatriu(String[][] arraystrings,int f,int c) {
  ff=f;
  cc=c;
  compsToExperiment=new JPanel();
  GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(ff,cc);
  compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);

  this.setContentPane(compsToExperiment);

  for (int filas=0;filas<ff;filas++){

    for (int columnas=0;columnas<cc;columnas++){
      if (arraystrings[filas][columnas].equals("gat")){

        JLabel cat2 = new JLabel();
        cat2.resize(1270/cc, 750/cc);

        cat2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("cat.png"));
        compsToExperiment.add(cat2);

        /*cat2.getSize();
        //cat2.getWidth();
        //cat2.getHeight();
        cat2.resize(width, height);
        cat2.setBounds(x, y, width, height)
        cat2.setSize(width, height)
        cat2.
        */

      }

      if (arraystrings[filas][columnas].equals("rat")){
        JLabel rat2 = new JLabel();
        rat2.setSize(1270/cc, 750/cc);
        rat2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("raton.png"));
        compsToExperiment.add(rat2);
      }

      if (arraystrings[filas][columnas].equals("menjar")){
        JLabel comida2 = new JLabel();
        comida2.setSize(1270/cc, 750/cc);
        comida2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("comida.png"));
        compsToExperiment.add(comida2);
      }

      if (arraystrings[filas][columnas].equals("res")){
        JLabel nada2 = new JLabel();
        nada2.setSize(1270/cc, 750/cc);
        nada2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("nada.png"));
        compsToExperiment.add(nada2);
      }
    }
  }

  this.repaint();
  //compsToExperiment.repaint();
  compsToExperiment.setVisible(true);
  //this.setVisible(true);
  //this.setVisible(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do custom painting to scale the image to the space available in the grid.

You can try using Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) (or maybe the Shrink Icon).